# Can't access Windows 10 after creating manual partitions and installing Ubuntu 15.10 Dual Boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, acer

I know that this question has been asked several times before, but I have not yet discovered a solution that works.

If I explain step-by-step what happened, perhaps someone might be able to suggest a solution. For your information, I use an Acer 64 bit laptop.

1. I selected 'other' under installation options, and created my own partitions as instructed.
2. I clicked install. Installation went fine, until there was an error somewhere near the end.
3. Couldn't boot into Ubuntu, so turned the computer off.
4. Turned the computer back on, and was just getting blinking white dash at top left hand corner of screen.
5. Pressing f2 or f12 caused the computer to bleep.
6. Reinstalled Ubuntu successfully - assigning it to partitions I had created before (I think).
7. Ubuntu worked, but no boot option for Windows.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post the output of  `sudo fdisk -l`. It's a print out of the existing partitions.

Comment: UEFI or BIOS system? And are both Windows & Ubuntu installed in same boot mode? If UEFI post this as fdisk only currently works for MBR and UEFI uses gpt: `sudo parted -l`

Comment: This question is almost certainly a duplicate, but *which* question it duplicates depends on the answer to oldfred's question.

Answer (score -1):

There are similar answers in other threads with the same issue but it is most likely a bios issue and your hard drive not knowing what to boot.
Try entering into bios. It's different on all computers but generally is del or f12. Make sure you assign your hard drive as the first boot or try resetting the values.